# GDAL Intersection Returns None

Tags: gis, intersection, gdal, nonetype

I am trying to compute the intersection between two features from separate geometries (one is Albers projection, the other WGS84). While the geometries are separate they both seem to project accurately when visually previewing the polygons, and the Intersect method confirms that the two do indeed overlap.  Other examples of this code have worked as I expected. Despite this, the intersection method returns None...

Both geo1 and geo2 are instances of the 'osgeo.ogr.Geometry' class.

```
geo1.Intersects(geo2) #Returns True (as expected)

geo1.Intersection(geo2) #Returns None (why!?!)
```

[A snapshot of my jupyter notebook session (along with visualizations of the polygons) is available here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnhFM.jpg)

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Reformatted....